# How to see full description, When issuing "display ip interface description" ?? on huawei router

Tags: router, cli, huawei

I have a router with many interfaces when I issue the command
display ip interface description I get something similar to this

```
Eth-Trunk1.444                 10.2.2.2/28   U    U    <= Gige E To You...
```

how can I see the full description ? 
remove the dots ?

Comment: Have you tried `display interface description`?

Comment: I want to see both the IP address and the FULL description

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible on Huawei routers/switches to display the full interface description, when using the command `display ip interface description`.

Huawei writes on their description of the `display ip interface description` command output:

> Description:
>
> Indicates the description of an interface, expressed in characters. A
>   maximum of 20 characters can be displayed. When the length of the
>   description is greater than 20 characters, only the first 16
>   characters are displayed and the last 3 characters are replaced by
>   ellipsis (...). If the description of an interface is the default
>   setting, no information is displayed.

Source: https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000088743?section=j007

See table **4-12**.

The only way to see the full scription is by using the `display interface description` command.